# What is the efficient way of showing .gif in android?

Tags: android, animation, webview, gif

So many ways are there. Using webview is the best way of doing it? Frame animation is good for it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it using frame animation. But What's the efficient way of showing .gif? I tried using webview too. Here is the code

```
public class GifWebView extends View {
    private Movie mMovie;
    InputStream mStream;
    long mMoviestart;
    private boolean play;

public GifWebView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
    super(context);
    mStream = stream;
    setPlay(true);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mMoviestart == 0) {
        mMoviestart = now;
    }
    final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration());

    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 20, 20);
    if (play) {
        Log.i("reltime", "" + relTime + ",duration:" + mMovie.duration());
        this.invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
};

public boolean isPlay() {
    return play;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize a `gif` image (without a `WebView`), you'll have to break it up into frames and animate each one of them, take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html):

Another mean for that is:

http://www.imagemagick.org/

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#adjoin

OR

http://www.gif-animator.com/

http://www.xoyosoft.com/gs/

Comment: I don't see the code, but the `WebView` approach is by my opinion the most efficient.

Comment: I tried custom view for showing .gif and add this view to normal relative layout not to webview. Have you ever tried it? Coz as far as i check there is no problem in animation. Whats say? I don't know whats the need of web view there which all are talking about.